# SQL Database Powered C# & ASP.Net Role based authentication control

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, ssms, user-roles

I want an ASP.net and C# authentication/logon control which references a SQL server database containing two tables: users and roles. When the authentication is successful, I want the user to be redirected to a specific page on the website determined by their role stored in the database.

For example, a user with a role of *"System Admin"* would be directed to the protected home page within the system admin folder on the site where as a role of *"System User"* would be redirected to their respective home page within the protected system user folder.

I managed to find something on the MSDN library but this redirects all successful logons to "default.aspx" regardless.

Is there a way to:

1. A way to alter this to my specific requirements?
2. A resource that I havent found yet that could provide some pointers into how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get there with the built-in SqlMembershipProvider and SqlRoleProvider present in ASP.NET since version 2.0.

Real problem is determing what "role" a user should be in when they have multiples.

Answer (score 0):

You could always have a proxy login successful page, that gets the role after a successful login and redirects to the subsequent page.

code behind of the successful default.aspx login.

```
if(Context.User.IsInRole("System Admin")){
    //redirect to page.
}
```